# UIViews are overlapping when we change simulator orientation at run time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, autolayout

In my project i have added two `UIViews` programmatically using Auto Layout.

Using `UIView` animation when I click secondView button in my below screen I am pushing first `UIView` to secondView `UIView` and when I click firstView button I am pushing back from second `UIView` to first `UIView`.

My problem is that when I change the simulator orientation at runtime the Second `UIView` overlaps the first `UIView`. Please help why this problem is happening.

I know this is a constraints problem but how can we resolve this problem?

### My code:-

```
#import "ViewController444.h"

@interface ViewController444 ()
{
    UIView * firstView;
    UIView * secondView;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController444
@synthesize DetailsView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    firstView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    firstView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    firstView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [DetailsView addSubview:firstView];

    secondView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    secondView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    secondView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [DetailsView addSubview:secondView];

    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(firstView,secondView);

    [DetailsView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[firstView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [DetailsView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[firstView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    [DetailsView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[secondView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [DetailsView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[secondView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    secondView.hidden = YES;

}

- (IBAction)firstViewAction:(id)sender {

    secondView.hidden = NO;

    secondView.frame=CGRectMake(firstView.frame.size.width+20, 0, firstView.frame.size.width, firstView.frame.size.height); // starting visible position

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         [secondView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, firstView.frame.size.width, firstView.frame.size.height)];  // final visible position
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)secondViewAction:(id)sender {

    secondView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, firstView.frame.size.width, firstView.frame.size.height); // starting visible position

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         [secondView setFrame:CGRectMake(firstView.frame.size.width+20, 0, firstView.frame.size.width, firstView.frame.size.height)];   // final visible position
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}
@end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your **problem** is because you're trying to do layout in two different ways, which is generally (well, always!) a bad idea. You have some Auto Layout code, which is great and definitely the right solution, but then you're programmatically trying to calculate and set the frames of your views, which does *not* play well with Auto Layout.

Your **solution** is to modify your constraints in your animation so that Auto Layout always has complete control over them. You can either create new constraints to reflect your new position (required if you're trying to change the `multiplier` value) or just adjust the values you have right now.

You might be interested to know that you can add competing sets of Auto Layout constraints then enable only the ones you want for a specific layout. You could also consider moving your UI to a storyboard, creating your constraints there, then creating `IBOutlet`s for those constraints so you can manipulate them in code.

Comment: can you tell me through some code because i am very new for this technology

Comment: I did try and provide some specific code but it's awfully hard with only a small slice of your project. Briefly, set up all the constraints you need to be able to reproduce all states of your program, then enable/disable them based on the current circumstance. If you can animate one set of constraints instead (just change their `constant` value directly) you'll find that substantially easier.

Comment: you mean do i have to "clear" and "add" the constraints when change orientation right?

Comment: Again, you can choose: 1) remove constraints and re-add, 2) use competing constraints and enable/disable, 3) use one set of constraints and change their constants.

Comment: please provide some code how to do this and i am really not understand and more ever i am very new for this technology

Comment: Like I said, "it's awfully hard with only a small slice of your project." If you want people to have any chance of helping you, you'll need to upload your project somewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98407/discussion-between-abhiram-and-twostraws).